# if and for loop in one line

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am approaching an excel via openpyxl and I need to do elif statment and for loop at the same line of code.

What I want to achive is this:

Check if the value is not None, if not None do a loop in a column in which you are looking for an index of matched value. 
If you do not find the value in this column, check the second column, where the value is. I have to create an elif statment, which would guide machine to do similar thing as it is doing in 'else:' statment which I can handle as I can write it in a chain and multiple lines

The code I have:

```
for each in sheet['G'][1:]:
    indexing_no = int(sheet['G'].index(each)+1)
    indexing_column = int(sheet['G'].index(each))

    if each.value == None:
        pass
    else:
        for search_value in sheet['A'][1:]:
            if each.value == search_value.value:
                index_no = int(sheet['A'].index(search_value) + 1)
                sheet['H{name}'.format(name = indexing_no)].value = sheet['B{name}'.format(name = index_no)].value
```

Comment: *I need to do elif statment and for loop at the same line of code*. Why need you that?

Comment: Because in else statement I am looping only thru one column. I need to create conditionals to check first one column and then the other if not find in the first column.

Comment: Sounds like you should also loop over the columns.

Comment: I need to do: if each.value in for search_value in sheet['D'][1:]:

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
columns = ("G","A","D") # column letters to search in parallel
values  = ( ((c,v) for v in sheet[c][:1]) for c in columns )
for row,colVal in enumerate(zip(*values),1)
    col,value = next( ((c,v) for c,v in colval if v is not None),("",None))
    if not col: continue # or break when no column has any value
    # ...
    # perform common work on first column that has a non-None value
    # using col as the column letter and value for the value of the cell
    # at sheet[col][row]
```